# Enviar mail en laravel en producción failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username error 534

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando enviar un mail en laravel, lo cual anda perfecto en local pero en producción me es imposible, me surgen un millón de errores. Este es el problema que me surge ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe que significa?

Este es el ENV:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=ltomicb@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=merluzadepincho@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Merluza de Pincho"
```

Comment: porque tienes `smtp.gmail.org` no debería ser `.com`? Si ese no es el problema, intenta borrando el cache en producción `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Si, me percaté hace un rato, ahora estoy intentando resolver el problema que acabo de subir.

Comment: Pega el error como texto por favor..

Comment: Es un error muy grande, no me alcanzan los caracteres: "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "ltomicb@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message..."

Comment: Intentaste borrando el cache en producción `php artisan config:clear`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba estos pasos para la solución del problema

- Debe permitir aplicaciones menos seguras, puede hacerlo haciendo clic debajo del enlace https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- Usa una contraseña de la aplicación: Si usas la verificación en dos pasos, intenta acceder con una [contraseña de la aplicación](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).
- Permite el acceso de apps menos seguras: Si no usas la verificación en dos pasos, es posible que tengas que [permitir que apps menos seguras accedan a tu cuenta](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).
- Si las sugerencias anteriores no resuelven el problema, visita https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha y sigue los pasos que se indican en la página.
- Si modificas el `.env` ejecuta `php artisan config:clear`

---

Fuente:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636865986363810933-1186759849&rd=2#cantsignin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927470/8451749

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo, excelente respuesta, me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 0):

Funciona: --Si modificas el .env ejecuta

```
php artisan config:clear
```

O mediante Putty:

```
root@server.e**ng.org [~]# php /home/usuario/app/artisan config:clear
```